# Extra argument "method" in call. Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire to do a get request to Yelp api, i got my post request woking but my get request is not working what so ever, i have tried everything i read from other questions but still no solution. here are my codes.

This is my post request which is working.

```
class func getAccessToken() {
     let parameters: Parameters = ["client_id": client_id, "client_secret": client_secret]
     Alamofire.request("https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).response {
         response in
         print("Request: \((response.request)!)")
         print("Response: \((response.response)!)")

         if let data = response.data {
         let dict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSDictionary
         print("Access Token: \((dict["access_token"])!)")
         self.accessToken = (dict["access_token"])! as? String
         self.tokenType = (dict["token_type"])! as? String
         }
    }
}
```

This is my get request that i'm having trouble with.

```
class func getRestaurents(searchTerm: String) {
        let parameters: Parameters = ["term": searchTerm, "location": "******"]
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [tokenType!: accessToken!]
        Alamofire.request("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search", method: .get, parameters: Parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).response {
            response in
            if let data = response.data {
                let dict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [] as! [NSDictionary])
                print(dict)
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: It should be `parameters` not `Parameters`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing class `Parameters` instead of its object `parameters`.

```
Alamofire.request("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search", method: .get, parameters: Parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).response {
```

Should be:

```
Alamofire.request("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search", method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).response {
```